# Only display new records in a MS Access continuous form

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am making a continuous form for entering data into a table. Currently the form displays all existing data entries. Is it possible to only display the initial empty entry and basically hide the existing ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the form to always display only new entries, set its *Data Entry* property to *Yes*.  That setting is found on the *Data* tab of the form's property sheet.

Alternatively, you can leave *Data Entry* set to *No* but ask for data entry mode when opening the form via `DoCmd.OpenForm`:

```vb
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="Form1", DataMode:=acFormAdd
```